# Подключение Google Maps Java и Directions Api

Tags: java, spring, google-maps-api

Имеется проект на Spring Boot.

Встала задача подключить **Google Maps**, а именно нужен его функционал маршрутов между точкой А и Б. (**Directions API**).
Мне нужно передавать координаты, которые у меня есть и строить маршрут между двумя координатами.

Подключить карту мне удалось, встроил в **html код JS, API Key**. Карта не такая красивая и функциональная как у самого гугл мапс, но это не важно.

Включил режим с поиском маршрутов, пришлось еще places API включить и вроде строит маршруты, но много но.

Во первых у меня стояла таска имплементировать это через Java. У них есть библиотека для Java, но я не понимаю суть работы. Понятно, что я должен передать координаты в строку запроса, потом отправить POST запрос на сервера гугл, получить ответ с расстоянием, массивом точек и прорисовать маршрут на карте, но документация гугла скупа на такое, а опыта у меня не так много. Может кто подскажет в какое направление двигаться.В гугле почти нет инфы для Java, в основном для Андроида.
Через Postman я затестил, запрос отправляю, ответ получаю. Вопрос как его прорисовать на карту с помощью библиотеки гугла.